# Magento 2 Payment Method Hacked

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, security, security-patch, issue

My website's checkout was hacked this 4th time.
The hacker somehow modifies the following files:

- lib/web/jquery.js
- vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php
- vendor/magento/framework/Message/Session.php

and adds some kind of encrypted scripts and code, which hides all the payment methods and shows a custom credit card payment option.
I have tried multiple solutions:

- changing passwords (FTP/ssh/db/admin),
- making ssh access with a private key only,
- changing admin URL, and website folder permissions.
  But still, he is able to hack again n again.

My hosting is on a managed server. I asked the hosting provider (since they have the root access) and they told me that it could be because of some kind of plugin (not sure).

What could be the possible solution? Please help. The upgrade to the latest magento is already in progress, but don't know whether it would be the solution.

Comment: What version are you using ? Did you applied the latest patches (which can be done faster than an upgrade) ? How many third party modules are you using ? Any custom dev/theme ? How fast does the hack come back after fixing the files ?

Comment: Magento version is 2.3.2. Which security patches should I apply directly?
I am using some 3rd party modules, but majority of them are paid.
The 1st hack was in Jan. Then Mar, and from last week its been 3 times already now. And same files are changed

Comment: You have to check files and folder properly set for your projection. You have must check this

Comment: Also use Web firewall like Cloudflare or surcuri

Comment: Also screen code base using Anti virus  software

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps to recover the website checkout.

Step 1: Identify all the affected files in the setup.

Step 2: Review the code of all third-party extensions to check for issues.

Step 3: Replace all affected files with Magento default files and ensure there is no malicious code in the third-party extensions.

Step 4: Update FTP or SFTP details, and also change Magento admin credentials.

Step 5: Scan the database for any injected malicious content.

Step 6: Adjust file and folder permissions according to the Magento guide.

You can refer to the guide provided below for more information:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: Step 1 - already provided. I have identified and mentioned the affected files in the Issue.
Step 2 - How and what to check in third-party extensions?
Step 3 - How? Since only vendor files can be replaced I guess, and extensions can be upgraded.
Step 4: already done. Still hacked
Step 5: How?
Step 6: already did